# How to render data of stored procedure to the update'form?

Tags: yii2

How to render stored procedure'data to the update'form and send data of create's form to stored procedure?

Controllers:
For index form I used:

```
public function actionIndex(){ 
     return $this->actionListar(); }


public function actionListar(){
    $listadoClientes = $gestor->listar(); //listar() is the sp       
    $provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $listadoClientes,
        'key' => 'IdPersona',
    ]);
    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
    ]);
}
```

And for the view I used:

```
public function actionView($id) { 
    $detallesCliente = $this->actionDame($id); 
    return $this->render('view', ['dataProvider' => $detallesCliente,]);... 
}

public function actionDame($IdPer)
{
    $gestor = new Clientes();
    $detallesCliente = $gestor->dame($IdPer);
    return $detallesCliente;
}
```

Views: 
Index.php:

```
<?= GridView::widget([ 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,'columns' => 'Apellidos',...], ]); ?>
```

Views.php

```
 <?= DetailView::widget(['model' => $dataProvider,'attributes' => [
 [label' => 'Apellidos',
  'value' => ArrayHelper::getValue($dataProvider, 'Apellidos'),
  ],
  ]); ?>
```

I try to use ArrayDataProvider or array with ActiveRecord, but I can't find the way. When I try it, shows me the following error:

> Call to a member function `isAttributeRequired()` on array

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to put the following at the end of the method that calls the stored procedure:

```
$result= $query->queryOne();
$this->setAttributes($result);
```